# Use Laravel as a proxy

Tags: php, .htaccess, proxy, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a website that uses WordPress, Magento, and Laravel 4.

Everything will be under the same domain name.

The website will be in multiple languages.

Each framework will be in it's own folder:

- **WordPress:** /blog
- **Magento:** /store
- **Laravel:** / (root of the website)

Since I am using multiple languages I don't want to see the word **blog**, and **store** appear in the URL when the user access the website with another language than english. So my solution is to use Laravel routing as a proxy.

e.g:

English:

- **WordPress:** //website/blog/[...](params for WordPress)
- **Magento:** //website/store/[...](params for Magento)

French:

- **WordPress:** //website/blogue/[...](params for WordPress)
- **Magento:** //website/magasin/[...](params for Magento)

Etc...

But WordPress, Magento are all in the same folder whatever the language is.

I don't want to have multiple copies of Magento...

So is there a way to do this with Laravel 4, with Apache .htaccess or maybe with just some simple dry PHP?

Comment: If you're using Apache you should be able to do this using mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html - Laravel on Apache uses this to allow nice URLs for routing.

Comment: Lots more information here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html - you could try using an Alias directive: `Alias /blog /var/www/wordpress` (specify the full path in the file system though)

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45197416/470749